# Laptop flashing/blinking in between on Fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install via USB

Tags: boot, drivers, 16.04, graphics, acer

I bought a new Acer E5-573 Laptop a week back. I am facing this weird issue where the screen is blinking/flashing in between the work.

It has on board Intel HD Graphics 5500 card.

Is this some hardware related issue or graphics issue?

I tried running `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` but it didn't help.

Comment: Anything suspicious in `dmesg` or `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` or `~/.xsession-errors`?

Comment: Try [this suggestion](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/intel-hd-graphics-5500-flickering-4175555870/#post5433387).

Comment: I didn't get anything over there. Can you please simplify it a bit

Comment: Just write the content that the linked comment mention into the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`, reboot, and see whether it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is long running bug of Intel driver https://bugs.launchpad.net/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1432194

Let's try different desktop environment, like [MATE](http://mate-desktop.com/). Some guy said it works.

Comment: @Suraj be be sure to look at [this comment to the linked bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1432194/comments/36).